# Copying files out of LXC container without starting it

Tags: linux, arch-linux, lxc

Is there a way to copy files out of an LXC container without starting it?

The context for this is that I'm using Crostini on my ChromeOS device. Crostini is a VM that allows you to run LXC containers in a sandboxed environment for local development. An update to the development channel/branch seems to have broken my weird setup (my container is a non-default Arch container with the username changed, which doesn't play since they only test the default Debian container working).

Anyway, that should all be fairly irrelevant to the underlying goal here: I want to copy my home directory (or all files, I don't really care as long as I can access my home directory elsewhere) from the LXC container so that I can start from scratch. The only reason I include it is because it means I can't modify the container to start in privileged mode, and generally don't have root access even in my LXC host.

Comment: Which backingstore are you using for the container?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa BTRFS

Comment: @A.B I was successful in this. I'll add it as a separate answer and accept it.